# This correlated subquery example seems wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I found this example on https://sqlbolt.com/topic/subqueries
[image]

Isn't the "dept_employees" on the last row of the query should refer to a table? From the row before it shows that it is a column.

I have tried to run it on MySQL and got "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'dept_employees.department' in 'where clause'"

Comment: It does refer to a table.  It refers to the `employees` table referenced in the subquery.  I can't tell what the relationship is between the query and the question, but the syntax does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Yep, this query is syntactically valid in every version of MySQL at least since 5.5

Comment: You should copy the text of the image directly in your question to avoid problems if the image was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be simplified to this but I do not know anything about MySQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE salary >
(
    SELECT AVG(revenue_generated)
    FROM employees
    WHERE department = employees.department
)
```